Which MS Graph permissions are Entra ID members granted by default and are they related to their assigned roles?
Consider the following Azure CLI command for fetching an access token for MS Graph after signing into the Azure:
az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph
In this case, the access token has the following permissions with an audience of https://graph.microsoft.com/:
"scp": "AuditLog.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All email Group.ReadWrite.All openid profile User.ReadWrite.All"
How do I see in Entra ID that my user is assigned these MS Graph permissions? Are they related to my user's assigned Entra ID roles? If so, where do I see the mapping from roles to MS Graph permissions?
Thanks in advance!
